# Access nested model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have following setup:

```
class EmpsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @emp = Emp.new
    @unit_options = Unit.all.collect{|unit| [unit.name, unit.id] }
  end

  def create
    @emp = Emp.new(emp_params)
    @emp.save!
    redirect_to :action => :list
  end

  def destroy
    @emp = Emp.find([:id])
    @emp.destroy
    redirect_to :action => :list
  end

  def list
    @emps = Emp.all
  end

  def emp_params
    params.require(:emp).permit(:name, :unit_id)
  end

 end
```

Model:

```
class Emp < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :units
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :units
end
```

Form:

```
<p> List of Employees: </p>
<table>
<% @emps.each do |u| %>

    <tr>
<td><%= u.id %></td> <td><%= u.name %></td>  <td><%= u.unit_id %></td>   <td><%= link_to "Delete", u, :method => :delete %></td>
</tr>
<% end %> 
</table>
```

All I want to do is to print (in table above) unit attribute called :name related with Emp printed Emp object.

Found various related solution but they do not apply to my case.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't include a "form", but rather just a table.  What is the output you're getting or do you get errors?  If so, please updated your question to include backtrace errors.

Comment: Sorry ... I meant table... you are right ... EDITED

Comment: the table above works properly .... but it only prints referenct (:unit_id) instead of unit_name. I have no idea how to print unit name

Comment: can you update your question to list the data attributes from schema.rb fo your 2 models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `:units` as the association name, it "has one unit" no "units", Rails convention over configuration expects the association to be singular.

Then you should be able to do `some_emp.unit.name`.

Or you can use method delegation:

```
class Emp < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :unit

  delegate :name, to: :unit
end
```

And now you can do `some_emp.name`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I will let you know tommorrow if it works as I don't have access to code right now

Comment: Work as charm. Altough I had to change has_one to belongs_to as I picked wrong association :) thank dude